# Golang regex extract from match

Tags: regex, go

I need to use regex to extract and replace some text.

Any word that has the following needs to be replaced:

- sub-19  -> u19
- sub19   -> u19
- (sub19) -> u19

I have the following but it's missing one of the requirements and can't figure it out 100%

`(?i)sub(?:[^a-z|0-9])`

Comment: "*Any word that has the following needs to be replaced*"... So can any of these sample be a substring of a larger word and that **whole** word needs to be replaced? Otherwise, do you mean something like `(?i)(?:sub-?19|\(sub19\))` maybe?

Comment: The only example is that the word SUB can be anywhere in the string and i do not want to replace then

Comment: Have managed to get the following 
`(?i)sub(?:[^a-z|0-9])|sub(?:[^a-z|-])`
e.g.  
Croacia (Sub21) -> sub2
Croácia Sub-21  -> sub-
Croácia Sub21    -> sub2

But i would need the ones that are followed by the 2 to just be sub

Answer (score 1):

You can match non whitespace chars before and after and replace with group 1

```
(?i)\S*sub-?(\d+)\S*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XIrYLh/1)

Example

```
package main
import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)\S*sub-?(\d+)\S*`)
    var str = `sub-19
sub19
(sub19)`
    
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(str, "u$1"))
}
```

Output

```
u19
u19
u19
```

---

If you don't want to remove leading and trailing non whitespace chars, you can omit the `\S*` and add a word boundary `\b`

```
(?i)\bsub-?(\d+)\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BCWqtf/1)

Comment: I only want to match the sub or sub- so i can replace that and keep the numbers

Comment: @ChristopherBennett You don't want to keep the parenthesis right?

Comment: it's not a big deal if it's there

Comment: @ChristopherBennett In that case you could also use `(?i)\bsub-?(\d+)\b` See  https://regex101.com/r/BCWqtf/1

Comment: that's perfect! Thanks so much